# solving $x\,dx + xy^2\,dx + y\,dy + yx^2\,dy=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have to solve $x\,dx + xy^2\,dx + y\,dy + yx^2\,dy=0$

Dividing by $dx$ we have

$x + xy^2 + yy' + yy'x^2=0$

From where,

$$\frac{yy'}{1+y^2}+\frac{x}{1+x^2}=\frac{y\,dy}{1+y^2}+\frac{x\,dx}{1+x^2}=\\ =\frac{d(y^2+1)}{1+y^2}+\frac{d(x^2+1)}{1+x^2}= \frac{1}{2}d\ln(1+y^2)+\frac{1}{2} d\ln(1+x^2)=\frac{1}{2}d\ln(1+y^2)(1+x^2)=0$$

Let $c=(1+y^2)(1+x^2)$, so our equation becomes:
$$
d\ln c=0
$$

So what should I do here, should I integrate, or should I divide by $dx$?

If I divide by dx I get the expression $2x+2yy'+2xy^2+2x^2yy'=0$ which has $x$, $y$ and $y'$ and doesn't help me get anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: integrate from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$d( \text{something})=0 \implies \text{something = constant}$$

So you get the solution $$\ln(1+y^2)(1+x^2) = C$$ (Where $C$ is arbitrary constant)

Comment: and from there I can exponentiate the equation. What stopped me from doing this was the arbitrary constant. Is this a sufficient solution, i.e. having an unknown constant?

Comment: @Nikola Yes, it is sufficient. Actually this constant is just similar to constant of integration. Infact, we have integrated "0" , which therefore results in a constant.

Answer (score 3):

$$d\ln c=0 \implies \ln(c)=K$$

Another Hint

$$x\,dx + xy^2\,dx + y\,dy + yx^2\,dy=0$$
$$(x + xy^2)dx + (y + yx^2)dy=0$$
It's an exact differential...
$$\frac {\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac {\partial Q}{\partial x} \implies 2xy=2xy$$
$$
\begin{cases}
f(x,y)=\int x+xy^2dx \\
f(x,y)=\int y+yx^2dy 
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore
$$\boxed{x^2+y^2+y^2x^2=K}$$

Answer (score 2):

The DE is
$$\frac12d(x^2)+\frac12d(y^2)+\frac12d(x^2y^2)=0$$
Then, the solution is
$$\boxed{\frac12x^2+\frac12y^2+\frac12x^2y^2=c}$$

Comment: Doesn't $d(xy) = y dx + xdy$ and not $xdx + y dy$?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. If we take the differential, we get $d(xy + \frac 1 2 x^2 y^2) = y dx + xdy + xy^2 dx + yx^2 dy$, which is not the same as the original $xdx + ydy +  xy^2dx  + yx^2dy=0$. I think the answer should be $x^2y^2 + x^2 + y^2 = c$ instead.

Comment: @TrevorNorton  You are right ...

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos So we put all the expressions under the sign of the differential and than we integrate? A lot quicker, thanks.

Comment: @Nikola, yes, it is a method known as integrating combinations.

Answer (score 2):

$$x\,dx + xy^2\,dx + y\,dy + yx^2\,dy=0$$
$$(1+x^2)y\,dy =-(1+y^2)x\,dx $$
If $x^2,y^2\ne-1$, above equation can be written as (after multiplying both side by $2$):
$$\frac{2y}{1+y^2}\,dy =-\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\,dx $$
$$\int \frac{2y}{1+y^2}\,dy =-\int \frac{2x}{1+x^2}\,dx $$
$$\ln (1+y^2)=-\ln (1+x^2)+\ln c=\ln \frac {c}{1+x^2}$$
where $c$ is a constant. Hence,
$$1+y^2= \frac {c}{1+x^2}$$
$$y^2= \frac {c}{1+x^2}-1$$ Or:
$$y^2+x^2+y^2x^2= C$$ where $C$ is also a constant.

Answer (score 1):

it is $$-\frac{y'(x)}{\frac{1+y(x)^2}{y(x)}}=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$